# Kali Linux - run './pycharm.sh' by running 'pycharm' in terminal

Tags: bash, shell-script, path, alias

Currently I need to access the folder in my desktop, and then a `bin` subfolder to reach `./pycharm`.

So I want to automate all of:

```
cd Desktop
cd pycharm-community-2021.3.1
cd bin
./pycharm.sh
```

to

```
pycharm
```

I would like to ease the process by just inputting 'pycharm' in the terminal and have it launch. I'm aware Linux is incredible for such things - I just forgot how its called and how its done so. If someone could point me in the right direction. I would appreciate.

Comment: Have you added the full path to it to your PATH environment variable? For `bash`, you want to add the line `export PATH="${PATH}:~/Desktop/pycharm-community-2021.3.1/bin"` to the end of the file `.bashrc` (or `.profile`, or whichever shell startup file is appropriae for your shell of choice). (The `export` is also not really needed in this case, but get in the habit of being explicit now to avoid frustrating problems later...)

Comment: You could also, from within the `~/Desktop/pycharm-community-2021.3.1/bin` direcory, create a symlink, `ln -s pycharm.sh pycharm`, which will enable you to simply type `pycharm` without the leading `./` or `.py` extension.

Comment: Hi C.M, for the first comment as it is the most relevant, I did not fully understand, could you elaborate? I do admit of being a linux newbie..

Comment: I would suggest then that you find an online introduction/tutorial to working with Unix/Linux and the various shell command lines. That is far outside the scope and purpose of this site.

Answer (score 0):

An alias is a good fit for this use case:

```
alias pycharm="~/Desktop/pycharm-community-2021.3.1/bin/pycharm.sh"
```

Add this to your shell's customization file. As an example, that's `~/.bashrc` for the bash shell. You can then run `pycharm` as intended.

Comment: Tried this, wont launch and terminal wont recognize the alias for some reason..

Comment: @ThomasReiner If you added the line to the bashrc file, you need to start a new shell instance so that it can read the bashrc file. If you want to do this on the current shell instance, just run the command as `alias pycharm..... ; pycharm`.

Comment: New terminal wont work either. 'alias pycharm' returns 'command not found'. I'm running kali.

Comment: An alias has several problems: (1) Various shell syntax is not always easily portable between different shells. (2) It will not get sourced if called from a non-interactive shell. (3) It becomes cumbersome to maintain should you want to restructure your file system. (4) It requires (re)loading in to the current shell and/or all terminal sessions.

Comment: @ThomasReiner Maybe you're running a different shell. In any case, Kali isn't a suitable distro for a newcomer to Linux. There's already a learning curve for Linux, and Kali would just make it more difficult.

Comment: @Haxiel I do understand that, I've had my rodeos with it so far, installing it on and off for the past few years and now I've finally set it up on my work-pc at my home office, so I don't get discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by C.M, created a symlink:

> from within the ~/Desktop/pycharm-community-2021.3.1/bin directory
> `create a symlink, ln -s pycharm.sh pycharm, which will enable you to simply type pycharm without the leading ./ or .py extension.`

Then copied the symlink to Desktop.